# Вертикальный слайдер без overflow: hidden

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет. Пожалуйста, посоветуйте карусель контента (вертикальную) на jquery, но чтобы в ней не использовался тег `overflow: hidden`. Замучался уже, не могу найти. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Разбейте Ваш контент карусели на блоки, чтоб он был в пределах этой карусели (не выходил за рамки). Далее последовательно изменяйте видимость этих блоков, оставляя видимым только 1.
P.s. хотя можно и не разбивать на блоки, а просто скриптом отсчитать кол-во элементов и изменять видимость каждого элемента, но первый вариант менее затратный по ресурсам.